# What is the Pathfinder equivalent of a Harry Potter "Portkey"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

In the Harry Potter books, a Portkey is an object that can transport a person to another location.

The Portkey can be any old object, and is set up in advance to activate at a set time or upon being touched. When it activates, the portkey and anyone touching it are teleported to the location chosen when it was set up. They can be any old object, like an old boot, and in Harry Potter they're usually a piece of junk nobody would touch so that nobody accidentally gets Portkeyed anywhere. (So an old boot is often *exactly* what it is.)

Note that Portkeys are use-once (until they get set up again) and move *with* you.

What **existing** magic spells or magic items can be used as an equivalent or substitute?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say that *[refuge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/refuge)* (Wiz 9 / Clr 7) would probably fit the bill:

> When you cast this spell, you create powerful magic in a specially prepared object. This object contains the power to instantly transport its possessor across any distance within the same plane to your abode.
>
> Once the item is so enhanced, you must give it willingly to a creature and at the same time inform it of a command word to be spoken when the item is used. To make use of the item, the subject speaks the command word at the same time that it rends or breaks the item (a standard action).
>
> When this is done, the individual and all objects it is wearing and carrying (to a maximum of the character’s heavy load) are instantly transported to your abode. No other creatures are affected (aside from a familiar or animal companion that is touching the subject).

Issues:

1. The material component is 'a prepared object worth 1,500 gp' so old boot might not work
2. The spell specifically teleports the target to the caster's 'abode', not a location of their choosing
3. The item is destroyed when used so no repeated uses
4. Only a single target can use it, unlike in HP where any number of people touching the portkey would be teleported (as I recall)

Other than that, pretty close. I'd imagine you could get around some of the issues with a lenient DM:

1. You could have a seemingly worthless object that is actually worth a lot (an old boot with platinum aglets on the laces and a pure silk sole, for example)
2. The caster could officially establish residence where they want the portkey to send people to (get a deed, pay rent to the landlord, etc.) to get around the 'abode' part
3. The spell's description doesn't say that the material component is consumed, just broken, so *mending* could theoretically fix it
4. There's no reason you couldn't put a bunch of *refuge*'d objects next to each other; for example, *refuge* several spools of platinum thread and sew them into the boot, so each person touching the portkey would technically be using a different one

Comment: Half a pound of adamantium would be easier to 'hide' in an object than 1500 coins of platinum.

Comment: @Ifusaso 150 coins. The item's worth is measured in gp - gold pieces, and one platinum piece, or coin, is worth 10 gp.

Comment: Err... Right. Still easier to put half a pound in than 150 coins worth.

Comment: Does adamantine have a cost per pound in PF? I couldn't find one.

Comment: @J.Fox No, like 3.5, per pound prices are specified for darkwood and mithral, but not adamantine.  (And with mithral being valued at only 500gp per pound it's actually worth exactly as much as platinum: 50pp to a pound X 10gp per pp = 500gp worth of platinum per pound.)

Comment: Also, the spell doesn't have to specify that the item is destroyed; it is listed as a material component, not a focus, and being destroyed (by the energies of the spell, not the caster) is inherent to the definition of material components, as listed in the Magic chapter's Spell Descriptions section.